# Javah Not Recognizing class (A) mentioned in class (B) when operating on class B

Tags: java, java-native-interface, classpath, package, javah

I'm trying to get a jni header for class B, and class A sits in the same package, right next to it.

Class B contains native functions (for which I need the JNI Header)

and I use the command

```
javah -jni ClassB -classpath (path to jarfile containing all the classes necessary, including classA)
```

and I get the response

"Couldn't find class w.x.y.z.ClassA"

Where w.x.y.z is the right package path for classA and classB.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the options first, and only at the end the `ClassB` argument.

Also, the classpath should point to the root of the package hierarchy, not to the package directory. Then call it like this:

```
javah -jni -classpath library.jar w.x.y.z.ClassB
```

Comment: Bingo. I navigated to the folder containing 'w', moved my jar file there, then javah w.x.y.z.ClassB worked great. Thanks man!

Comment: You can also use relative paths for the jar files.